# Why does adding + in front of a float make it 33% faster in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I'm computing the second raw moment of large arrays in Node and I've been trying to find ways to make it faster. Interestingly, it became a lot faster just by adding a `+`.

Here's the original function:

```
const fn = (arr) => arr.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x**2, 0);
```

Here's the modified function, which is about 33% faster:

```
const fn2 = (arr) => arr.reduce((sum, x) => sum + (+x)**2, 0);
```

This is around the same speed as the modified function:

```
const fn3 = (arr) => arr.reduce((sum, x) => sum + (12.34 + x)**2, 0);
```

Here's the code to get the average time:

```
const avgTime = (fn) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    const hrTime = process.hrtime();
    const startTime = hrTime[0] * 1000000 + hrTime[1] / 1000;
    fn();
    const hrTime2 = process.hrtime();
    sum += hrTime2[0] * 1000000 + hrTime2[1] / 1000 - startTime;
  }
  return sum / 100;
}

const arr = Array(1000000).fill(0).map(_ => Math.random());

avgTime(() => fn(arr));
avgTime(() => fn2(arr));
avgTime(() => fn3(arr));
```

I know the JS engine makes optimizations if it knows the variable type, which is why asm.js adds `|0` to the end of integers. However, in this case, since I'm using `**` on the variable `x`, shouldn't the engine already know it's a number? Why does adding the `+` help?

Also, are there ways to make this even faster without using a GPU? (All the GPU libraries use CUDA, which I don't have.)

Comment: I ran them each several times independently, it shouldn't be CPU optimizations. The arrays are too large to fit in cache anyway.

Comment: *“Also, are there ways to make this even faster without using a GPU?”* Not tested on real data, but `arr => { let sum = 0; for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { const x = arr[i]; sum += x * x; } return sum; }` does well in the benchmark (1/20 of the time).

Comment: Live snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/cpgodbsz/

Comment: Because someone told V8 that `+` guarantees that `+x` is a number and can be optimized, while `x**2` doesn't.

Comment: Note that coding techniques that make one implementation run faster may well make another run slower, so test widely in the implementations you intend the code to run on.